# C# “String may be null here” but I don't think it can be null

Tags: c#, string, null

So I wanted to make a sort of “name checker” that’s always had the first letter be capital and the rest lowercase. I got that to work but whenever I got past the name checker and wanted to use the name in future code, it would always say “string may be null here.” I have tried many things like adding a ? But nothing works. I don’t think it can be null but maybe I’m wrong. Here is my code here:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string? name, choice;
        bool finishnameingcharacter;
        finishnamingcharacter = true;
        while(finishingnamingcharacter == false)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
             name = Console.ReadLine();
             name = name?.ToLower();
             if(name != null)
             {
                 name = char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);
             }
             Console.WriteLine("");
             Console.WriteLine("Your name is " +name+ ", is that correct?");
             Console.WriteLine("");
             Console.WriteLine("1: Yes");
             Console.WriteLine("2: No");
             choice = Console.ReadLine();
             if(choice == "1")
             {
                 finishnamingcharacter = 1;
             }
             if(choice == "2")
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("");
             }
             else
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Invalid Claim")
             }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

The "name" at the bottom is where the error is. If there's any confusion about my question ask me. I tried my best to explain it.

Comment: [`Console.ReadLine` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-6.0#returns): _"The next line of characters from the input stream, or null if no more lines are available."_

Comment: At what point do you believe `name` becomes guaranteed not null? Which statement do you think does that?

Comment: Charlieface, It has to go through a checks to even get to the Console.WriteLine(name); code. It can't get to that if it is null I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @UnowedStart If `name = Console.ReadLine();` assigns `null` to `name`, then `name = name?.ToLower();` will assign `null`. `if(name != null)`'s condition will be `false`, so the `if` statement will be skipped, and then `name` as used in `Console.WriteLine` will be `null`.

Comment: @Charlieface So what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Change the while loop to a do/while loop then the loop is guaranteed to execute once and the compiler knows then that name can’t be null - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-while-and-do-while-loop

Comment: [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8) is already nullable - it's not necessary to use `?`  when declaring a string variable. Have a look at [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.8) and  [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Don't you see  "bool finishnameingcharacter;   finishnamingcharacter = true;" are different? The first one "nameing" is typo

Answer (score 0):

I could not compile your code, so I made some changes

```
static void Main()
{
    var name = string.Empty;
    var choice = string.Empty;
    do 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        name = name?.ToLower();
        if (name != null && name.Length>1)
                name = char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);
        
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + name + ", is that correct?");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("1: Yes");
        Console.WriteLine("2: No");
        choice = Console.ReadLine();
        if (choice == "1") break;
        
        if (choice == "2")Console.WriteLine("");
        else Console.WriteLine("Invalid Claim");
    
        } while (true);
        
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Comment: A `while` loop is also known as an 'entry-controlled loop' - if the first test is `false` then the loop will never execute.

It's clear to a human that the loop _will_ execute, but not to the compiler.

The fix in this answer is to use a `do ... while` loop - an 'exit-controlled loop' - where the loop is executed at least once even if the first test is `false`. Then the compiler can be sure that `name` is set before being used.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a nullable string in this software?

You didn't initialize the `name` at the beginning, if your loop will never run, then the `name` output line will be NULL. This is what your error points to.

It is better to initialize variables before their first use, as they can be NULL by default (valid for reference types such as classes). For a string, one option would be `String.Empty`

```
string name = String.Empty, choice = String.Empty;
```

These two lines can be combined:

```
 bool finishnameingcharacter;
 finishnamingcharacter = true;

 // Replaced by
 bool finishnameingcharacter = true;
```

On the next line in the `while` loop, you check the condition: `finishingnamingcharacter == false`. The loop checks the condition and only then executes. To execute the loop, you need the condition to be TRUE, but it will not take this value, because earlier you defined the variable `finishnamingcharacter = true`. `true != false`. By default you need to define this variable as `false`

```
bool finishnameingcharacter = false;
```

The user can enter an empty string value, so converting it to lowercase immediately doesn't matter, as long as it checks for an empty string. There is a special method for checking if a string is empty: `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` - it returns true if the string is empty or null.
If the user entered the wrong name, then we need to ask him to enter again, for this, the `continue` operator is used.

```
name = Console.ReadLine();
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, your name is empty. Please enter again.")
    continue;
}
//So if name is not empty: jOhN
name = name.ToLower(); //john
name = char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1); //John
```

For boolean values it is better to use reserved words, i.e. instead of `finishnamingcharacter = 1` it is better to write `finishnamingcharacter = true`

Rest of the code looks good. We all took the first steps :)

Full modified code here:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string name = String.Empty choice = String.Empty;
        bool finishnameingcharacter = false;

        while(finishingnamingcharacter == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, your name is empty. Please enter again.")
                continue;
            }
            //So if name is not empty: jOhN
            name = name.ToLower(); //john
            name = char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1); //John

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Your name is " +name+ ", is that correct?");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("1: Yes");
            Console.WriteLine("2: No");
            choice = Console.ReadLine();

            if(choice == "1")
            {
                finishnamingcharacter = true;
            }
            else if(choice == "2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Claim")
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

PS There is a special method [TextInfo.ToTitleCase()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=net-6.0) *"wAr aNd pEaCe to titlecase: War And Peace"* - I advise you to read